# TeX Gyre Cursor sometimes renders incorrectly

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, ligatures

```tex
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}

\begin{document}
    \texttt{We shall fill in the blank.}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the spacing between `fi` seems incorrect:

[image: LuaLaTeX Output]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want TeX Gyre Cursor without ligatures. So you can use:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Ligatures={NoRare,NoCommon}]

\begin{document}
    \texttt{We shall fill in the blank.}
\end{document}
```

to get

[image: “We shall fill in the blank.” without “fi“ ligature]

If you want to set the feature only locally, you can use `\addfontfeature` inside the argument of `\texttt`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}

\begin{document}
    \texttt{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon}We shall fill in the blank.}% without fi ligature

    \texttt{We shall fill in the blank.}
\end{document}% with fi ligature
```

See the `fontspec` manual for more information about font feature `Ligatures`.